# Проблема с sequence.pad_sequences(keras)

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, numpy, keras

**Код:**

```
MaxDescriptionLen = 0
for item in descriptions:
  if len(item) >  MaxDesscriptionLen:
    MaxDesscriptionLen = len(item)
x_train = sequence.pad_sequences(x_train, maxlen=MaxDesscriptionLen)
x_test = sequence.pad_sequences(x_test, maxlen=MaxDesscriptionLen)
```

**Проблема:**
После прогона `x_test` и `x_train` все матрицы состоят полностью из нулей. Почему так происходит?

Comment: Что представляют из себя x_train и x_test? Можете привести воспроизводимые примеры данных?